# Get the index of a row(meets certains coinditions)

Tags: python, pandas

Its an heuristics for a knapsack problem

```
select = df[df['Wi'] == df[(df['path'] != 0) & (df['path'] != 1)]['Wi'].min()]
  g = np.where(df.loc[select, 'Wi'] <= currentcapacity, True, False)
  if g:
      df.loc[select, 'path'] = 1
      totalvalue += df.loc[select, 'Vi']
      totalweight += df.loc[select, 'Wi']
      currentcapacity -= df.loc[select, 'Wi']
      items += 1
  else:
      df.loc[select, 'path'] = 0
```

I want to select the minimum value of the Weight column 'Wi',taking on account that column 'path' that matches that value is not equal to 0 or 1.

if the selected value is less than the current capacity, the 'path' will be 1

Comment: It helps if you can provide a minimum reproducable example. It's difficult to help without being able to see a sample of the DF you're working on and the desired output.

Comment: I manage to get the correct values. but throws me this:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\brian\Desktop\TSOR\knapsackinstance.py", line 32, in <module>
    select = df[df['Wi'] == df[(df['path'] != 0) & (df['path'] != 1)]['Wi'].min()]    ['Wi'].item()
  File "C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 349, in item    raise ValueError("can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar")
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
PS C:\Users\brian\Desktop\TSOR>